# trimr package in R not returning results

Tags: r

I want to use the trimr package to remove outliers from my data, but it doesn't return any sensible results. I followed the code as instructed online:

`trimmedData <- sdTrim(data = exampleData, minRT = 150, sd = 3, 
                      perCondition = FALSE, perParticipant = TRUE, 
                      returnType = "mean", digits = 0)`

and from a data file with 4 variables like this:
`> head(exampleData)
  participant condition accuracy       RT
1          10         1        1 1720.456
2          10         1        1 1628.178
3          10         1        1 1727.709
4          10         1        1 2246.926
5          10         1        1 1246.832
6          10         1        1 2812.077`

I end up with this:

`> head (trimmedData)
  participant X1 X0
1           1 NA NA
2           2 NA NA
3           3 NA NA
4           4 NA NA
5           5 NA NA
6           6 NA NA`

Is it to do with the original file or my code or something else? This function would be very useful for me but I don't know why it won't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your columns to exactly match what function expect. In your case 
`colnames(exampleData)[4] <- 'rt'` fixes the problem and function will return you expected result.

Comment: I never would've thought! Especially because in the code "minRT" is capitalised. Is this inherent to R language or can I use different column names if I change them in the code?

Comment: You would need to modify sdTrim function. Check its documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/trimr/versions/1.0.1/topics/sdTrim

Comment: @Agata please consider accepting answer if it helped you solve a problem.